# How to find the persons name with a bitcoin wallet address

Tags: wallet

I want to know who I sent money to. I need to know because I believe I was scammed

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. Bitcoin does not work by names, emails, or material things of that nature. Bitcoin works in an anonymous way where public keys are the names and private keys the persons. There is no way to figure out what you are asking, At all.